Calculate a set of rows with from_date and to_date based on a single date column
I have an customer_audit table, that logs INSERT and UPDATE happened on a customer table.
customer_audit



id
operation
timestamp
customer_id
address1
address2




1
I
2024-10-05
100
link st
number 1


2
U
2024-10-06
100
link st
number 2


3
U
2024-10-07
100
link road
number 2


4
U
2024-10-08
100
link road
number 200


5
I
2024-10-06
200
park st
number 20


6
U
2024-10-08
200
park st
number 200



The expected output, in this case for address1 and address2, displays all historical values for address1 and address2 separately, with from_date and to_date calculated from the timestamp column.
E.g. for customer_id 100:



customer_id
column_name
column_value
from_date
to_date




100
address1
link st
2024-10-05
2024-10-07


100
address1
link road
2024-10-07
null (meaning column value is current)


100
address2
number 1
2024-10-05
2024-10-06


100
address2
number 2
2024-10-06
2024-10-08


100
address2
number 200
2024-10-08
null



I managed to solve it by tweaking what mcwolf's query a bit:
select customer_id, name, 'address1' as attribute_name, address1 as "attribute_value", min(from_date) as "valid_from", max(to_date) as "valid_to"
from (
select customer_id, 
       name, 
       address1,
       "mod_timestamp" from_date,
         COALESCE(lead("mod_timestamp") over change_window, to_date('99991231', 'yyyymmdd')) to_date,
       ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( PARTITION BY customer_id, address1 ORDER BY mod_timestamp) as rownum
from customer_audit
WINDOW change_window as (PARTITION BY customer_id order by mod_timestamp)   
order by customer_id, mod_timestamp ) a
group by customer_id, name, attribute_name, "attribute_value"
order by customer_id, "valid_from";


it is not clear, in the example result, where (and why) the value null (meaning column value is current) comes from. otherwise try something like this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qNeTX2FgnrPsXmfdG2WeEA/0

thanks for your reply. this seems to have created 2 rows for customer_id = 100 , address1 = link st. one with from_date as 2024-10-05 and to_date as 2024-10-06, and another with from_date as 2024-10-06 and to_date 2024-10-07. what I wanted to achieve is, to have only 1 row for address1 = link st. because the change on 2024-10-06, is actually for address2.

@muty20 Note that SO is no code writing service, so please show what you have tried and explain what exactly doesn't work as expected.

I managed to solve it by tweaking what mcwolf suggested it. have updated my post. thanks all

@muty20: Please read: Can you answer your own questions on Stack Overflow?, which does not advice you to edit the question....

... here is another way to do it ...
WITH
  dates AS    -- track changes of addresses ( ..._rn = 1 )
    ( Select ca.id, customer_id, "timestamp" as ts,
             address1, Row_Number() Over(Partition By customer_id, address1 Order By id) addr1_rn,
             address2, Row_Number() Over(Partition By customer_id, address2 Order By id) addr2_rn
      From   customer_audit ca
    ) 
--    M a i n    S Q L : 
SELECT  f.customer_id, 'address1' as column_name, f.address1 as column_value, f.ts as from_date,  
        Lead(ts) Over(Partition By customer_id, 'address1' Order By id) as to_date
FROM  ( Select  * From  dates Where addr1_rn = 1 ) f
UNION ALL 
SELECT  f.customer_id, 'address2', f.address2, f.ts, 
        Lead(ts) Over(Partition By customer_id, 'address2' Order By id) as to_date
FROM  ( Select  * From  dates Where addr2_rn = 1 ) f 
ORDER BY  customer_id, column_name, from_date

/*     R e s u l t : 
customer_id column_name column_value    from_date               to_date
----------- ----------- --------------  ----------------------  ----------------------
        100 address1    link st         2024-10-05 00:00:00     2024-10-07 00:00:00
        100 address1    link road       2024-10-07 00:00:00     null
        100 address2    number 1        2024-10-05 00:00:00     2024-10-06 00:00:00
        100 address2    number 2        2024-10-06 00:00:00     2024-10-08 00:00:00
        100 address2    number 200      2024-10-08 00:00:00     null
--
        200 address1    park st         2024-10-06 00:00:00     null
        200 address2    number 20       2024-10-06 00:00:00     2024-10-08 00:00:00
        200 address2    number 200      2024-10-08 00:00:00     null                    */

See the fiddle here.

Your appended answer does not seem to work for me. This does:
SELECT customer_id, 'address1' AS col_name, address1 AS col_value
     , min(timestamp) AS valid_from
     , max(to_ts) AS valid_to
FROM  (
   SELECT *, count(step OR null) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY timestamp) AS grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT customer_id, address1, timestamp
           , lag(address1) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY timestamp) <> address1 AS step
           , lead(timestamp, 1, '9999-12-31') OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY timestamp) AS to_ts
      FROM   customer_audit
      ) sub1
   ) sub2
GROUP BY customer_id, grp, address1
ORDER BY customer_id, grp;

fiddle
Repeat the same for address2 and append results. Both operations are mostly independent as they form different groups.
Related (with links to more):

How to group timestamps into islands (based on arbitrary gap)?
Generate new UUID per row depending on gaps in existing time series

